# Newtonsoft deserialize object

Tags: c#, json.net

string result is below:

`{
  "1": "something"
}`

```
string result = "{ \"1\"' : \"somestring\"}";

public class JsonData
{
    private string _1;

    public string 1 { get { return _1; } set { _1 = value; } }

    public JsonData()
    {
    }
}

JsonData data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData >(result);
```

I want to deserialize the `String` but JsonData definition is wrong. Whats wrong with this?

Comment: It's wrong because you can't start a member name (be it properties, fields, method, classes, namespaces...) with a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code won't compile since [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx) cannot start with numbers.

You can use the [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute__ctor.htm) to reference the `1` property inside the Json.

```
public class JsonData
{
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public string One { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var data = @"{ ""1"" : ""something"" }";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(data);
```

Comment: string result = @"
    {
     "data" : 
     {
      { "1" : "somestring" },
      { "2" : "somestring" },
      { "3" : "somestring" },
      { "4" : "somestring" },
      { "5" : "somestring" },
      { "6" : "somestring" },
      { "7" : "somestring" },
      { "8" : "somestring" },
      { "9" : "somestring" },
      { "10" : "somestring" },
      ... to many
     }
    }
";